# Mysql error PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away using Laravel and curl request

Tags: php, mysql, linux, laravel, mariadb

I am using a 3rd party API to insert data in the database. I encountered this problem already in my local computer and I set the `max_allowed_packet` as what other posts said and it worked for me. But now I am using our linux remote server to insert the data. I cant find the `my.ini` or some config file but there are similar file and here named `50-server.cnf` are some he contents of it

```
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 1024M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 32M
query_cache_size        = 1024M
```

I have also written a bunch of queries in our linux remote terminal in order to set the global variables. Here are some of it

`sudo mysql`

`SET SESSION wait_timeout = 999999;`

`SET SESSION   net_read_timeout = 1000`

`SET GLOBAL   connect_timeout = 1000;`

after that i run 
`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`
then I execute my controller function but I still get 
`PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away`

I am using

Mysql:
`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.43-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Linux:
`Linux ip-172-31-16-16 4.15.0-1054-aws #56-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 7 16:15:59 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

PHP:
`Zend Engine v3.3.11, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies`

MariaDB:
`mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.43-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Can someone tell me what is the problem with this?

Comment: `query_cache_size = 1024M` is much too high; the QC does not scale well.  Drop that down to 50M.

Comment: Please provide the specific statement(s) involved.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

1. Your settings are useless - after restart default values from my.cnf configuration file will be used. Also `SET SESSION` changes values for the current connection.
2. Check the following things:

   - Is it a server bug (e.g. server crash)? . After the error occured,
     log in via mysql command line client and check the uptime of the
     server with `\s` or `status` command.
   - Open the error log file of MariaDB server go to the end and check if there is some useful information.
   - Try to execute the statement (which is passed to PDO::execute) in mysql command line client.
   - In case of a SELECT statement, make sure the size of result set doesn't exceed the `max_allowed_packet` size.
   - Capture traffic with tcpdump, open the file with wireshark, set filter to `mysql` and check if you can find more information.